# Only 1 LESS CSS file is active

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to embed multiple `.less` files like this

```
<head>
  <link href="mine.less" media="screen" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" />
  <link href="friend.less" media="screen" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

but I'm finding that only the first one is used and the other one gets dropped. In normal .css files, multiple .css files are allowed. Is .less different or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: There is no evidence on the homepage that multiple files aren't supported. How do you know that the second one is not working? Are you sure the file is loading? Maybe a syntax error is causing it.

Comment: @Reiner Gerecke I found out from the troubleshooting I did. 1. I copied the content from the first file to the second (first now empty) and I got nothing. 2. I copied the content from the second file to the first (second now empty), and it worked. The code itself is working, but it depends on where it is. Only when it's in the first file it works. @Myles Gray's solution to do import works. I now have only 1 file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using `@import [FILENAME.LESS];` in the master .less file?

As per:
http://techportal.inviqa.com/2010/12/17/lessphp-php-implementation-of-less-css/